# LaTeX, SQL comments, hyphens converted to en dashes in lstlisting

Tags: sql, latex, comments, listings

The SQL comment character consists of two hyphens, thusly:

```
-- cannot create table if one already exists
drop table if exists mytable;
```

When using lstlisting in package listings for source code, the comment characters are converted to en dashes. If I insert a space between the hyphens, it looks like [hyphen][space][hyphen], instead of two hyphens next to each other. So, using lstlistings in package listings for SQL source code, how do I specify the comment characters?

Comment: Huh, that sounds like pretty bad behavior from a package whose purpose is to wrap unformatted source code. Can you share your LaTeX too?

Comment: (And, as usual, if it doesn't work the first time, compile it twice, or thrice!)

Comment: \documentclass{article}

    \usepackage{listings}
    \lstset{
        breaklines = true,
        language = SQL,
        numbers = left,
        basicstyle = \footnotesize,
        escapeinside={}
    }
   

\begin{document}    

        \begin{lstlisting}
.echo on
.headers on

-- Name: Your Name
-- File: Your File Name
-- Date: Today's Date

-- SQL code
-- DROP table

-- CREATE table

-- INSERT data

-- SELECT data
        \end{lstlisting}

\end{document}

Answer (score 0):

Actually, someone pointed out that the hyphens as comment characters displayed properly. The issue is that the space between them is so small as to be indistinguishable. With a high quality printed document and a magnifying glass, you can see the space. On my display, a rather small one, the two hyphens bleed together.

Thanks for looking at this.